# Is this index selection useless?

Tags: c#

I'm reviewing some code and I came across this:

```
// Select the last parameter in the list
if (parametersListBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    parametersListBox.SetSelected(parametersListBox.SelectedIndex, true);
}
```

`ParametersListBox` being a C# `ListBox`. Despite the fact that the comment is wrong, does this actually do something or is this just useless code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear to be useless but it might be firing some bindings that aren't setup correctly in the first place.

Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For more on set selected.

Only thing I can suggest is to comment it out and do some testing.

Answer (score 2):

The check is needed, because `SetSelected()` would throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

See reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/a.html#fcae9a622a947f54 or read the documentation where it clearly states

Condition for `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

> The specified index was outside the range of valid values.